# Facebook custom story preview before posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is there anyway we can show a preview for Facebook's custom stories for users before they posting on their timelines?

If not something provided by Facebook, is it OK if we implement the same CSS/HTML code that Facebook uses or there are restrictions on doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing such default preview method, but yes you can implement this if you want. There's no such restrictions in doing this.

In fact, they prefer showing user the story somewhere in the application that you are going to publish on their behalf.